# Is it possible to automate a Reset password link?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, reset-password, automation-testing

Im trying to create test script for a reset password link but when I run it, there is an "Unable to locate element:" error. I just re-used a test script from a running feature. Is it possible to automate a Reset password link?

I used the driver.findElement(By.xpath: with a valid xpath

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.